# Make Cortana listening after app starts for further app commands?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, cortana

How can I make Cortana listen for further commands from my VCD like navigating to other pages after the app was started with "Hey Cortana" -> "App name" -> "Command".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you have already launched your app from Cortana and handle the navigation in the `OnActivated` method, then I agree with @stefan.s. But if you want to navigate to specific page through vcd command when cortana launching your app, I can give you a sample.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to navigate after launching the app with Cortana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the application cortana will not work.

But you can use the SpeechRecognizer class (I would imagine, that this triggers the same cloud services in the background as cortana).

There is a blog series about how to do that on the "Building apps for windows" blog at:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/16/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-its-good-to-talk/

> In Windows 10, speech is front-and-center with the Cortana personal
>   assistant, and the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) gives us several
>   ways to plug into that “Hey, Cortana” experience. But there’s much
>   more that we can do when working with speech from a UWP app and that’s
>   true whether working locally on the device or remotely via the cloud.
>
> In this 3-part series, we will dig in to some of those speech
>   capabilities and show that speech can be both a powerful and a
>   relatively easy addition to an app. This series will look at…
>
> - the basics of getting speech recognized how speech recognition can be
> - guided how we can synthesize speech additional capabilities in the
> - cloud for our UWP apps
>
> Read more at
>   https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/16/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-its-good-to-talk/#w3HXZcpS9M4UVm8S.99

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems that I have to check the SpeechRecognizer class.